# While updating state can't bind updated value inside the render

Tags: android, react-native

RN V 0.63
**react-native-carousel-view**

I need to change state value, while calling updateState method. click event and state updating fine. but the updated state value can't bind with render on first my click. ie: carousel child.

example:

```
updateState(){
    ... logic here
}
render(){
   return(
        <View>
            <Carousel
                extraData={this.state}
                delay={1000}
                loop={false}
                height={Height}
                scrollEnabled={false}
                animate={false}
                indicatorAtBottom={true}
                indicatorSize={10}
                indicatorText="●"
                initialPage={2}
                inactiveIndicatorText="○"
                inactiveIndicatorColor="#282828"
                indicatorColor="#3E0F82"
                onRef={ref => (this.child = ref)}
                onPageChange={(number)=> 
                this.getActivePage(number)}>
                    <View style={{flex:1,paddingHorizontal: 20}}>   
                        <Text>{this.state.status}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex:1,paddingHorizontal: 20}}>
                        <Text>{this.state.valOne}</Text>
                        <Text>{this.state.valTwo}</Text>
                    </View>
            </Carousel>
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={()=>this.updateState()}/><Text>click</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: take the time to ask the question properly, provide your code, what you tried, people here are willing to answer your question for free, take the time to ask it

Comment: @WalterShub Okay. I have update my question.